# Filtering itertools permutations by the length of the resulting permutation python

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools, processing-efficiency

Hi I'm totally out of ideas.

I have the following list of substrings. I need to build permutations of these substrings that create strings that match specific criteria. Each substring can be used any number of times (i.e. with replacement) and the order of the substrings is irrelevant.

```
items = ["q", "q.", "qg", "q.g.", "q.g", "qgr", "q.g.r", "q.g.r.", "qghr", "q.g.h.r", "q.g.h.r.", "q.g.r.h", "q.g.r.h.", "qakky", "qakky.", "qak", "qak.", "qkgr", "q.k.g.r", "q.k.g.r.", "qkghr", "q.k.gh.r", "q.k.gh.r.", "qr", "q.r.", "q.r", "gokoaheo", "gokoaheo.", "goko", "goko.", "g", "g.", "r", "r.", "rhk.", "k.", "k", "rhk", "gho", "ghr", "gr", "kgr", ".", ".", "goh", "goho", "gho.", "goho.", "rohok", "rohok.", "roh", "roh.", "kat.", "q", "q.", "qgr", "qghr"]
```

*Each resultant permutation must be as follows*:

1. Start with a 'q'
2. Cannot end with a '.'
3. Must not have any of the following substrings: '..', 'ee', 'oo', 'll', 'gg', 'aa'
4. Must have no more than 2 'q's 'r's and 'g's ; No more than 4 'h's, 'o's ; no more than 5 'k's or '.'s
5. Cannot have more than 13 characters or less than 9.

Hence I wrote the following function to sift each permutation:

```
def badseq(item):

    patt=re.compile('\.$|^[^q]')

    lets = ['q','g','r','h','o','k','.','..','gg','oo','ll','aa','ee']
    nums = [2,2,2,4,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    if len(item) > 13 or len(item) < 9:
        return True
    for i in range(len(lets)):
        l=lets[i]
        n=nums[i]
        if item.count(l) > n :
            return True
        elif re.search(patt, item):
            return True
    return False
```

Is there a better way to do this than calculate so many permutations and then filter them out one by one?

```
completelist=[]
for repetitions in range(8):
    perms=["".join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(items, repetitions) if not badseq("".join(x))]
    completelist.extend(perms)
    completelist=[x for x in set(completelist)]
```

The problem is that because I don't mind how many repetitions there are and the substrings are all of different lengths, I don't know how many repetitions to use in the itertools argument. I have gone with 8 because there are a number of substrings of one or two characters but that I may be calculating lots of duplicates. Or I may totally misunderstand what I am doing here :)

I would really appreciate any ideas for a way of either filtering out permutations quickly so that there are less to generate; or a way of working out how many repetitions I need to cover all of them. I can post my full multiprocessing code but figured I'd try to keep this to the point per the SO newbie guidance (it is just pool.starmap the repetitions and list to a function basically like the above.

Comment: Do you need to create _all_ permutations of the substrings that match the criteria?

Comment: Nope not at all. I'd prefer not to because it would be quicker. But I don't know another way of making them. Any ideas?

Comment: How many substrings that match the criteria do you need to create?

Comment: All of them thats the thing